# Proguard line number issue

Tags: android, proguard

I got a wried issue with the proguard.
In my `proguard-rules.pro`, I already setup keep line number:

```
# Keep line numbers
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

And in my `build.gradle`, I open the `minifyEnable` both `debug` and `release`:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro', 'google-api-client.pro'

            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug

            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
            }
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro', 'google-api-client.pro'

            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I get a crash, the Debug output line number is correct, but the release line number is error. Here is the logs of debug with `minifyEnable`, the line number is correct:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke a virtual method on a null object reference
        at com.frontrow.vlog.ui.personalpage.PersonalPageFragment.musicClicked(SourceFile:952) // The line number is the right position at my source code.
        at com.frontrow.vlog.ui.personalpage.PersonalPageFragment_ViewBinding$e.a(SourceFile:244)
        at butterknife.internal.b.onClick(SourceFile:18)
```

But it's error that the line number is not correct at the release with the `minifyEnable`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke a virtual method on a null object reference
        at com.frontrow.vlog.ui.personalpage.PersonalPageFragment.musicClicked(SourceFile:1) // The line number is error.
        at com.frontrow.vlog.ui.personalpage.PersonalPageFragment_ViewBinding$e.a(SourceFile:1)
        at butterknife.internal.b.onClick(SourceFile:4)
```

How can I fix this that the release output can take the right line number?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figure out that is R8 issue.
I setup `android.enableR8=false` in the `gradle.properties` and the line number is correct.
It seems the gradle version large than `3.4.0` it will open the r8 by default.